# tikz-uml nest self call issue

Tags: tikz-uml

When I try to use tikz-uml to draw s sequence diagram, I found it's not possible to nest a self call.
for example, below code work fine since it's not a nest self call:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A.java]{A}

\begin{umlcallself}[op=funA(),return=0]{A}
\end{umlcallself}

\begin{umlcallself}[op=funB(),return=1]{A}
\end{umlcallself}

\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

But if I nest it as below, then compile will failure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A.java]{A}

\begin{umlcallself}[op=funA(),return=0]{A}

\begin{umlcallself}[op=funB(),return=1]{A}
\end{umlcallself}

\end{umlcallself}

\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compilation error is now solved. I will make soon a new release of tikz-uml.